# развертывание django на heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

После `git push heroku master` , получаю эту ошибку "error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в "https://git.heroku.com/stormy-ocean-54062.git". Подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связано ?

Мой файл requirements

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.2.7
django-bootstrap3==11.1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2019.3
reverse==0.1.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0
psycopg>=2.6.1
```

и Procfile

```
web: gunicorn site_before_django2.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Эта ошибка означает, что вышестоящий репозиторий сделал коммиты, которые будут потеряны, если вы нажмете. Сначала выполните «git pull», чтобы объединить, а затем нажмите еще раз.